# Reading from file to dynamic struct

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I would like to read from a file, line by line. Each line has 3 arguments guaranteed. First 2 are first and last name and third is age.
I want to make a linked list, in which, each node represents a person (line) in the file.
I don't know the size of the names so I made it dynamic. I also don't know the number of lines in the file, so I would like that to be dynamic too.

My approach was to use fscanf, but then I wouldn't know how much memory needs to be allocated prior to reading it.
The function convertToList is supposed to receive a file path of the file we wanna read, convert it to a linked list, then return the head node. (Open to improvements)

Check out my code and see where I got stuck:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum
{
    FALSE,
    TRUE 
}bool;

struct Node{
    char firstName[50];
    char lastName[50];
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct {
    struct Node *head;
}LinkedList;


struct Node * convertToList(char *inputFilePath);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if(argc != 4) {
        printf("Invalid arguments.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    if (strlen(argv[3])!=1) {
        printf("Invalid sorting type.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    char *inputFilePath = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(argv[1]) +1);
    memcpy(inputFilePath, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    char *outputFilePath = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(argv[2]) +1);
    memcpy(outputFilePath, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) +1);
    char *sortType = argv[3];

    //LinkedList* inputList = (LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    struct Node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head = convertToList(inputFilePath);
    printf("\n%s %s %d\n", head->firstName, head->lastName, head->age);
//              printf("\nsaaap\n");

    getchar();


}

struct Node * convertToList(char *inputFilePath) {
FILE* ifp;
ifp = fopen(inputFilePath, "r");
if (!ifp) { perror("fopen"); exit(0); }
struct Node *head = NULL;
struct Node *prev = NULL;
bool isHead = TRUE;
while(!feof(ifp))   {
    struct Node *tmp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = tmp;


    if (head==NULL) 
        head = tmp;

    fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %d\n", tmp->firstName, tmp->lastName, &tmp->age);
    prev = tmp;

    //Need to link to next node as well

}

fclose(ifp);
return head;
```

}

I know that the fscanf is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Also, how do I return the root? Is my approach gonna work?
And lastly, how do can I set the next node in the list? I don't see it happening with the current while loop.

Thanks.

Comment: As a suggestion, you don't have to cast the return of `malloc` and you should also avoid `while(!feof(ifp))`, because the EOF flag is only set once you try to read past the end of the file, so when you reach EOF (but you still have not passed) you will get garbage.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the casting. What do you suggest I use instead of `while(!feof(ifp))`?

Comment: you have a fundamental error and I think a problem understanding pointers, you allocate memory and point to it with `head` at line 5 of `convertToList` function, then you overwrite the pointer at line 11, you should initialize `head = NULL;` and then when you have the first node you just check `if (head == NULL) head = tmp;`

Comment: also this is wrong `char *inputFilePath = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(argv[1]));` because you are allocating memory for `strlen(argv[1])` characters hence it should be `char *inputFilePath = (char*) malloc(1 + strlen(argv[1]));` since `sizeof(char)` is `1` always and you need an extra character for the terminating null byte `'\0'`.

Comment: @iharob Ok, I will fix those and repost. Still, can you help me with how to link the nodes together?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to link the nodes this is how you can do it and use dynamic storage, here you go, I didn't think this very much but it is Ok.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node
{
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int   age;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *convertToList(const char *const inputFilePath);
void freeList(struct Node *);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct Node *head;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid arguments.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    head = convertToList(argv[1]);
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        struct Node *current;

        current = head;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %s %d\n", current->firstName, current->lastName, current->age);
            current = current->next;
        }
        /* do manupulations with the list, example above, print the values */
        freeList(head);
    }
    return 0;
}

void freeList(struct Node *node)
{
    struct Node *current;

    current = node;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        struct Node *next;

        next = current->next;
        if (current->firstName != NULL)
            free(current->firstName);
        if (current->lastName != NULL)
            free(current->lastName);
        free(current);

        current = next;
    }

}

size_t appendChar(char **buffer, char character, size_t length)
{
    char *temporary;
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return length;
    temporary = realloc(*buffer, 1 + length);
    if (temporary == NULL)
        return length;
    temporary[length] = character;
    *buffer           = temporary;

    return 1 + length;
}

struct Node *parseFileLine(char *line)
{
    char        *word;
    struct Node *node;
    char        *endptr;

    if (line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (node == NULL)
        return NULL;

    node->firstName = NULL;
    node->lastName  = NULL;
    node->age       = -1; // an invalid value;
    node->next      = NULL;

    word = strtok(line, " ");
    if (word == NULL)
        return node;
    node->firstName = strdup(word);

    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (word == NULL)
        return node;
    node->lastName = strdup(word);

    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if (word == NULL)
        return node;

    node->age = strtol(word, &endptr, 10);
    if (*endptr != '\0')
        node->age = -1;

    return node;
}

struct Node *getNode(FILE *file)
{
    char  *line;
    int    character;
    size_t length;

    line   = NULL;
    length = 0;
    while ((character = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (((char)character == '\n') && (line != NULL))
        {
            struct Node *node;

            length = appendChar(&line, '\0', length);
            node   = parseFileLine(line);
            free(line);

            return node;
        }
        length = appendChar(&line, (char)character, length);
    }

    if (line != NULL)
        free(line);

    return NULL;
}

struct Node *convertToList(const char *const inputFilePath)
{
    FILE        *ifp;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *current;
    struct Node *last;

    ifp = fopen(inputFilePath, "r");
    if (ifp == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        return NULL;
    }

    head = NULL;
    last = NULL;
    while ((current = getNode(ifp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (current == NULL)
            return head;
        if (head == NULL)
            head = current;
        if (last != NULL)
            last->next = current;
        last = current;
    }
    fclose(ifp);

    return head;
}
```

Here you can also print the nodes to see that the data is correctly there.

I think you don't understand what `malloc` is for and you don't know much about pointers too, in your `fscanf` you are storing data in `firstName` and `lastName` without allocating memory for it, they are not even initialized so you would get a segmentation fault.

Comment: You can see that you don't need to copy `argv[1]` nor `argv[2]` when it you use it. If for some other reason you must copy them, then you also must release memory when you are done with them.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I fixed it if you check in the code I reposted (Edited). But I wanted to try and avoid using `firstName[256]`. But I guess there is no way around it. I will post how I linked the nodes. Can you check it please tell me if it's okay?

Comment: of course you can avoid it, but you didn't ask for that.

Comment: Actually that was my biggest concern. But my self expression skills are very poor at 5am. Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: I'm getting "Segmentation fault: 11." Also I don't understand why I should free list? I would like to make manipulations on it after it is made.

Comment: And then you should `free` it. And I don't get a single memory error running this with valgrind.

Comment: You need to free `line` after while loop in `getNode` (leak). And EOF is not guaranteed to fit in a signed char, should be int. Reason for *“Segmentation fault: 11”* is likely because of the *freeList* function – as it does recursive calls on itself. If stack is small and/or input file is big enough you will end up with a stack overflow resulting in SIGSEGV. The program run out of space for where to store call pointers.

Comment: You are right about the leak, it would not happen always though, but it is possible. But I don't agree about the `freeList` function, it is not going to cause any problem since it is recursive by design, it free's the next node in case there is one, otherwise it just free's `node` and returns. And can you please ealborate on _If stack is small and/or input file is big enough you will end up with a stack overflow resulting in SIGSEGV_.

Comment: Each process has a finite amount of stack space. When you call a function a stack frame is created. This holds local vars, epb, return-address, params. In `freeList` on first call from main a frame is created with addr of head + addr to main etc. If node has next it calls itself creating a new stack frame, if that has next creates a new frame and so on. Not before end is reached (->next == NULL) the free-up starts. FIRST node to be freed is last in linked list, then it return to previous caller, and that frees its node etc. `head` being LAST node to be freed.10000 nodes==10000 stack frames.

Comment: By that I'm not sure what you mean by *“But I don't agree about the freeList function, it is not going to cause any problem since it is recursive by design …”*. As for *If stack is small **and/or** input file is big enough …* that is poor choice of words. Point being that stack size is environment dependent. If file is big enough, thus linked list long enough, it will cause overflow on stack by recursive calls to freeList ending in a SIGSEGV.

Comment: @Morpfh Thank you for the lesson, I fixed it now. Would you recomend a book to read about that.

Comment: Not any books in particular.All depending on what etc. [Intel software developers manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) can actually be a good read. Else for a quick intro one have Gustavo Duarte's articles like [Anatomy of a Program in Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/), [How the Kernel Manages your Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-the-kernel-manages-your-memory/), And perhaps rel. here [Journey to the Stack](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/journey-to-the-stack/)

Comment: @Morpfh Thank you, I'll take a look at all of them.

Answer (score -1):

A somewhat different approach.

### argv copying

First off, as mentioned, you do not need to copy `argv` values. Main reason for doing do is if you manipulate the values. There are also cases where one want to erase argv values as they can be read by `ps` and other tools, read from `/proc/` etc. For example some programs take passwords as argument, to prevent password to be readable by anyone having access to the system one typically copy the argument then overwrite the `argv` value.

It is however usually good practice to use variables for the arguments. It usually makes the code clearer, but also makes it easier to maintain if one do changes. E.g. implement flag arguments like `-f <filename>`.

### exit() and return from main()

You also `exit()` with zero on error. You would want to exit with zero on success, and other value on error or other. This is the norm. 0 == success. Some applications implement numeric exit codes that can mean different things. E.g. 0 is normal exit, 1 is not an error but some special case, 2 likewise 3 might be an error etc. For example `grep`:

```
EXIT STATUS
   The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.  If  an
   error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling code should
   check for '2' or greater.)
```

---

### scanf

When you use `scanf` to read strings there are some tricks that can be used to make it better. First off always use the size parameter.

```
char name[16]
sscanf(buf, "%15s", name);
```

Do also check items read:

```
if (sscanf(buf, "%15s %d", name, &age) != 2)
     ... error ...
```

Third you can also save number of bytes read by `%n`:

```
sscanf(buf, "%n%15s%n %n%d%n", &of1, name, &of2, &age, &of3)
```

---

### Usage

A very simple, but also quick and user-friendly thing, is to add a usage function.

Typically:

```
int usage(const char *self, const char *err_str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Usage: %s <in-file> <out-file> <sort-type>\n"
        "  Sort types:\n"
        "   f Sort by First Name\n"
        "   l Sort by Last Name\n"
        "   a Sort by Age\n"
        ,
        self
    );
    if (err_str) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "\nError: %s\n",
            err_str
        );
    }
    return ERR_ARG;
}
```

Then in `main()` you can quickly and clean add something like:

```
if (argc < 4)
    return usage(argv[0], "Missing arguments.");
```

A note on you validation of the `sort` argument. Instead of using strlen() you can check if byte 2 is 0.

```
if (argv[3][1] != '\0')
    ... error ...
```

Finally main could be something like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *in_file, *out_file, sort;
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int err = 0;

    if (argc < 4)
        return usage(argv[0], "Missing arguments.");
    if (argc > 4)
        return usage(argv[0], "Unknown arguments.");
    if (argv[3][1] != '\0')
        return usage(argv[0], "Invalid sorting type.");

    in_file  = argv[1];
    out_file = argv[2];
    sort     = argv[3][0];

    if (sort != 'f' && sort != 'l' && sort != 'a')
        return usage(argv[0], "Invalid sorting type.");

    if ((err = file_to_llist(in_file, &head)) != 0)
        return err;

    prnt_llist(stdout, head);
    free_ll(head);

    return err;
}
```

### malloc helpers

When dealing with a lot of `malloc`ing and similar it can be useful to add some helper functions. If you get a memory error you normally would exit right away.

```
void *alloc(size_t size)
{
    void *buf;

    if ((buf = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
        exit(ERR_MEM);
    }
    return buf;
}

void *re_alloc(void *old, size_t size)
{
    void *buf;

    if ((buf = realloc(old, size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
        exit(ERR_MEM);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

### Parsing of the file

As you want to have everything dynamically allocated and no limits (beyond system memory) one solution is to implement some sort of tokenizer. It can be helpful to use a struct to hold it together. Something like:

```
struct file_toker {
    FILE *fh;     /* File handle */
    char *buf;    /* Dynamic Read buffer */
    size_t size;  /* Size of buffer */
    size_t len;   /* Length of actual data in buffer. */
};
```

One point here is to keep length of tokens read. By this one do not need to keep using strlen etc.

If you can afford it it would usually be better to read whole file in one go, then parse the buffer. Optionally one can read file in chunks of say 4096*16 bytes, but then one get some complexity when it comes to overlapping lines between reads etc.

Anyhow in this example one byte is read at a time.

---

### Start code

Finally a starting ground could be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>     /* memcpy/strncpy */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno for fopen() */
#include <ctype.h>      /* isspace() */

#define ERR_ARG         1
#define ERR_FILE_FMT    2
#define ERR_MEM         3

struct Node {
    char *name_first;
    char *name_last;
    int age;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct file_toker {
    FILE *fh;
    char *buf;
    size_t size;
    size_t len;
};

/* ===============----- GEN HELPERS ------=================== */

int usage(const char *self, const char *err_str)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Usage: %s <in-file> <out-file> <sort-type>\n"
        "  Sort types:\n"
        "   f Sort by First Name\n"
        "   l Sort by Last Name\n"
        "   a Sort by Age\n"
        ,
        self
    );
    if (err_str) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "\nError: %s\n",
            err_str
        );
    }
    return ERR_ARG;
}

void *alloc(size_t size)
{
    void *buf;

    if ((buf = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
        exit(ERR_MEM);
    }
    return buf;
}

void *re_alloc(void *old, size_t size)
{
    void *buf;

    if ((buf = realloc(old, size)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error.\n");
        exit(ERR_MEM);
    }
    return buf;
}

/* ===============----- LINKED LIST ------=================== */

void free_node(struct Node *n)
{
    if (!n)
        return;
    if (n->name_first)
        free(n->name_first);
    if (n->name_last)
        free(n->name_last);
    free(n);
}

void free_ll(struct Node *n)
{
    struct Node *p;

    if (!n)
        return;
    for ( ; n ; ) {
        p = n;
        n = n->next;
        free_node(p);
    }
}


void prnt_llist(FILE *fd, struct Node *n)
{
    int i = 0;

    fprintf(fd, "NODELIST:\n");
    for ( ; n != NULL ; n = n->next) {
        fprintf(fd,
            "Entry %d {\n"
            "  Name: %s, %s\n"
            "  Age : %d\n"
            "}\n",
            ++i,
            n->name_last,
            n->name_first,
            n->age
        );
    }
}

/* ================--------- FILE TOKER ------------==================== */
/* Free / close reader. */
void free_ft(struct file_toker *ft)
{
    if (!ft)
        return;
    if (ft->fh)
        fclose(ft->fh);
    free(ft->buf);
    ft->fh = NULL;
    ft->buf = NULL;
}
/* Initiate reader. */
int ft_init(struct file_toker *ft, const char *fn, size_t buf_sz)
{
    ft->size = buf_sz;
    ft->len = 0;
    ft->buf = alloc(ft->size);

    ft->fh = fopen(fn, "r");
    if (!ft->fh) {
        perror("Unable to open file");
        return errno;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* Increase buffer size. */
size_t ft_increase(struct file_toker *ft)
{
    if (ft->size < 1)
        ft->size = 1;
    ft->size *= 2;
    ft->buf = re_alloc(ft->buf, ft->size);
    return ft->size;
}
/* Read and skip spaces (\n, \r, ' ', \t etc.). Return first non-space. */
char ft_skip_space(struct file_toker *ft)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(ft->fh)) != EOF && isspace(c))
        ;
    return c == EOF ? 0 : (char)c;
}
/* Read next token */
size_t file_tok(struct file_toker *ft)
{
    size_t i = 1;
    size_t max;
    int c;

    if (ft->size < 2)
        ft_increase(ft);

    ft->len = 0;
    max = ft->size - 1;

    /* Skip any leading spaces. Function return first non-space. */
    if ((ft->buf[0] = ft_skip_space(ft)) == 0)
        return 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(ft->fh)) != EOF) {
        /* If space, break. */
        if (isspace(c))
            break;
        /* Save char to buffer. */
        ft->buf[i++] = (char)c;
        /* If entire buffer used, increase it's size. */
        if (i > max)
            max = ft_increase(ft) - 1;
    }
    /* Null terminate. */
    ft->buf[i] = 0x00;
    /* Length without terminating null */
    ft->len = i;

    return i;
}
/* Read next space separated token and save it as new allocated string. */
int file_tok_str(struct file_toker *ft, char **out)
{
    if (file_tok(ft) == 0)
        return 1;
    *out = alloc(ft->len + 1);
    memcpy(*out, ft->buf, ft->len + 1);

    return 0;
}
/* Read next space separated token and scan it as int. */
int file_tok_int(struct file_toker *ft, int *out)
{
    if (file_tok(ft) == 0)
        return 1;
    if ((sscanf(ft->buf, "%d", out)) != 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

/* ===============----- FILE PARSER ------=================== */    
int file_to_llist(const char *fn, struct Node **head)
{
    struct Node *node = NULL, *cur = *head;
    struct file_toker ft;

    /* Initiate new file token reader, initial buffer size 4096 bytes. */
    if (ft_init(&ft, fn, 4096))
        return 1;

    while (1) {
        /* Allocate next node */
        node = alloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        node->name_first = NULL;
        node->name_last  = NULL;
        /* Read and copy first name. */
        if (file_tok_str(&ft, &node->name_first))
            break;
        /* Read and copy last name. */
        if (file_tok_str(&ft, &node->name_last))
            break;
        /* Read and copy age. */
        if (file_tok_int(&ft, &node->age))
            break;

        /* Link and save current for next iteration. */
        node->next = NULL;
        if (cur) {
            cur->next = node;
        }
        cur = node;
        if (*head == NULL)
            *head = node;
    }
    /* Free last unused node. */
    free_node(node);
    free_ft(&ft);

    return 0;
}

/* ===============----- MAIN ROUTINE ------=================== */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *in_file, *out_file, sort;
    struct Node *head = NULL;
    int err = 0;

    if (argc < 4)
        return usage(argv[0], "Missing arguments.");
    if (argc > 4)
        return usage(argv[0], "Unknown arguments.");
    if (argv[3][1] != '\0')
        return usage(argv[0], "Invalid sorting type.");

    in_file  = argv[1];
    out_file = argv[2];
    sort     = argv[3][0];

    if (sort != 'f' && sort != 'l' && sort != 'a')
        return usage(argv[0], "Invalid sorting type.");

    if ((err = file_to_llist(in_file, &head)) != 0)
        return err;

    prnt_llist(stdout, head);
    free_ll(head);

    return err;
}
```

Comment: _When dealing with a lot of mallocing and similar it can be useful to add some helper functions. If you get a memory error you normally would exit right away._ I don't see why would you exit on error, is it a requirement of some kind? If you had open files and other resources wouldn't it be better to cleanup before exit? And as far as I know, if you are dealing with a lot of `malloc` and similar, you should worry about alignment, not how you write your program, since `malloc` returns `NULL` on error, you know if it succeded or not.

Comment: And also, you are not answering the question.